# Checking form data whether already existed database or not in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have to update a form data , while this operation i have to check , is the new form filed (such as name , date_of_birth ) data is new or already existed in database . For this is any validation option available in Laravel 4 . Any ideas? or suggestion ? are welcome .

Answer (score 1):

#### To check the uniqueness:

You could add this to your model:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'name' => 'unique'
);
```

and then in the controller when you receive the data, you can do this:

```
$data = [
    'name' => Input::get('name')
];
$validation = Validator::make($data, model.$rules)


if($validation->passes()){
    //write your code
}else{
   return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)
}
```

#### To check if a value already existed

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'Your name')->first();
```

[Helpful resource](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)